# Is this a reduced relative clause?

Tags: grammar

I've read a sentence below from a British teacher:

"In 1999, the proportion of **people using** the Internet in USA was about 20%"

I think it should be:

In 1999, the proportion of **people who used** the Internet in USA was about 20%

This is because we cannot use "-ing clause" for single actions in the past. 
Am I correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **Using the Internet** is not a single action; presumably the sentence refers to people who habitually used it.

Comment: "we cannot use "-ing clause" for single actions in the past" -- source?

Answer (score -1):

**"... the proportion of** [the/all] **people** [who were] **using the Internet ..."**
does contain some reductions, but non-finite forms like this are not always referred to as *reduced relative clauses*.  The reduced verb ([were]) puts 'using' in the past, and is perfectly acceptable.
([the/all] depends on context - without a previous mention, 'all' is assumed)
([who] is often replaced with 'which' or 'that')
([were] is a copula that inherits its tense from the main verb 'was')

**"... the proportion of** [the/all] **people who used the Internet ..."**
contains a *[subject] relative clause* which cannot be reduced.

(**"... the people** [whom] **I talked to ..."** is an example with a *reduced [object] relative phrase*,
although only pedants require the object form 'whom' instead of the other pronoun choices)

**"... the people** [who were] **confused by the Internet ..."**
is an example with a passive non-finite verb - which some refer to as a *reduced object passive relative clause* (but they should then also recognize the '-ing' form as a *reduced object progressive relative clause*)

Comment: Sounds good. Could be a bit too much trouble for a non-native speaker, though.